# How can I run an ad in a new thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, admob, ads

I have the code to show an ad that is slowing things down, I want to use a different thread to show that so the game can go on with the view

I have tried doing `runnable r = new Runnable(`) and put the code there but it doesn't work

This is the start of the activity and `getAd();` is slowing things down quite a bit

```
AdView mAdView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AppConstants.initialization(this.getApplicationContext());
        getAd();
    }

    public void getAd(){
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-xxx");
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

This is the Runnable and I get several errors

```
    public void getAd(){
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-8682721479994774/8922639499");
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            }
        };

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

I expected it to be divided in a thread and make things quicker, but I'm a newbie and I can't properly use thread

Comment: Show how you used the runnable

Comment: done, added that part of code

Comment: Where do you start the runnable?

Comment: I don't think it really matters, it's wrong, I'd like to do a new one but I don't know how

Comment: Of course it matter. If you don't start it, it won't work

Comment: I start it right under mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);